# Change height of text field in search bar without searchcontroller swift

Tags: ios, swift, uisearchbar, textfield

I have a problem about resizing text field inside the search bar which is implemented as a designable custom xib without any search controller.

I am able to set intrinsic size for my search bar but when I changed height of search bar, distance between text field and border increases. Here are what I need to get and what I actually get.

[What I need to have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdlIj.png)

[What I have now](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XuYNy.png)

I can get textField subview of searchBar by using "searchField" key value. I have tried to change its frame size but nothing has changed. I have also tried to set constraints but it didn't work as well.

```
let textField = value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField
textField.clipsToBounds = true
textField.layer.cornerRadius = 15.0
textField.frame.size.height = 10
```

(Note: Since I also need to have a text field with curved corners, changing border style of text field is not okay for my case. If there's a way of setting corner radius as in the picture with borderless textfield, that solution is also appreciated.)

I'm sorry if there's already an answer to my question but I couldn't find one after a detailed research. I will be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constraints might be affecting the `textField.frame.size.height = 10`. What I suggest is that you go with constraints because you get more customizations. If you do so, you must delete `textField.frame.size.height = 10`. Also can you include the designable class in your post? That might be a solution/problem.

Comment: there is nothing else than overriding intrinsic size in designable class yet. When I attempt to set constraints for text field, i get an error like that "The view hierarchy is not prepared for the constraint".